# Randomly display list items

Tags: javascript, html, css

This must be simple one, but I am not able to get it working.
I am creating quiz program using Javascript. Here is my basic markup:

```
<ul>
<li>option1</li>
<li>option2</li>
<li>option3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>option1</li>
<li>option2</li>
<li>option3</li>
</ul>
....
<ul>
<li>option1</li>
<li>option2</li>
<li>option3</li>
</ul>
```

**Requirement:**
I have to randomly display the list items each time the page is loaded. I have this script for choosing the random option(taken from another discussion):

```
var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
for (var i = ul.children.length; i >= 0; i--) {
        ul.appendChild(ul.children[Math.random() * i | 0]);
}
```

But the problem is it only applies to the first ul element. I want this script to be run for all the 'ul' elements.

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.querySelectorAll` instead ([see mozilla doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll)).

Here the live code snippet:

```js
var uls = document.querySelectorAll('ul');
for (var j = 0; j < uls.length; j++) {
  var ul = uls.item(j);
  for (var i = ul.children.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    ul.appendChild(ul.children[Math.random() * i | 0]);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>option1</li>
<li>option2</li>
<li>option3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>option1</li>
<li>option2</li>
<li>option3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>option1</li>
<li>option2</li>
<li>option3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) instead of `document.querySelector`. This will give you an array of all `ul` in document. Then iterate through the array and do what you are doing for each of them.

```
var ul = document.querySelectorAll('ul');
for (var ulIndex = ul.length - 1; ulIndex >= 0; ulIndex--) {
    for (var i = ul[ulIndex].children.length; i >= 0; i--) {
        ul[ulIndex].appendChild(ul[ulIndex].children[Math.random() * i | 0]);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps. Not tested.

Answer (score 0):

You should query all required `ul`s, then iterate over them and apply your script.

```
var ul = document.querySelectorAll('ul');

function haveFun(ul) {
    for (var i = ul.children.length; i >= 0; i--) {
        ul.appendChild(ul.children[Math.random() * i | 0]);
    }
}

Array.prototype.forEach.call(ul, haveFun);
```